# How to write e2e test cases for highcharts-angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, protractor

I am trying to write e2e test cases using protractor for charts built using highcharts-angular in our application. I am querying for the series plotted in the chart and the tooltip values for a point in the series on mouse hover. The locators for those are shown below

```
getPlottedSeriesNames() {
    return element.all(by.css('.highcharts-legend-item>text>tspan')).getText();
}

hoverOverASeries() {
    return  browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('.highcharts-series-1>.highcharts-point'))).perform();
}

getTooltip() {
    return  element(by.css('.highcharts-tooltip-box>text>tspan')).getText();
}
```

And the spec file has the following things:

```
it('should have the all the series plotted in the chart', async () => {
    const desiredCount = 4;
    const plottedSeries = await occurrenceChart.getPlottedSeriesNames();
    expect(plottedSeries.length).toEqual(desiredCount);
});

it('should have desired tooltip properties', async () => {
    await occurrenceChart.hoverOverASeries();
    const tooltip = await occurrenceChart.getTooltip();// just trying to log the data of tooltip
    console.log('tooltip', tooltip);
});
```

I am able to get the plotted series in the graph, but getting the tooltips on mouser hover is not working as expected(may be I am doing it the wrong way) and i encountered the following error.

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .highcharts-tooltip-box&gt;text&gt;tspan)"><![CDATA[NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .highcharts-tooltip-box>text>tspan)
```

The mouse hover action is not working, so the tooltip is not available.

Is there a better approach to write e2e tests for highcharts in angular application.

Comment: Can you please also add your code from the spec file using this PO. So we can see the full picture and the sequence of action. Maybe this can be easily solved the usage of ExpectedConditions...

Comment: Adeed the spec file

Comment: I can see you also added an error message you are getting. My bad I assumed that this were a 'dummy locators' which obviously are not looking right. Can you please also provide an html you are interacting with

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock

Comment: @SyamPradeep, why you attached the code of `getPlottedSeriesNames` method? It seems unrelated and have no action in the actual test and in other locators, maybe I am missing something. Please correct the error message, because you have a typos in it in the end `box>text>tspan)">text>tspan)` so we will see the actual error. Also, you can try update `getTooltip` method like this `let tooltip = element(by.css('.highcharts-tooltip-box>text>tspan'));
        return  browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(tooltip)).then(() => {
            return tooltip.getText();
        });`

Comment: @Hidberg After adding the above piece of code for getting tooltip, I encountered the below error
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."><![CDATA[Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: @Hidberg,@YuriyGerasimovich Please find the code related to the question at the following link - https://github.com/syam38/highcharts-angular-e2e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `mouseMove` twice for tooltip pop up.

I don't know exactly why this behaviour happening, but you can see on a screenshot, that with one `mouseMove` you have bold border, but tooltip is not appearing
[image]

So you will have on `hoverOverASeries`

```
return browser.actions().mouseMove(webElement).mouseMove(webElement).perform();
```

Also locator `getTooltip` should be (">" changed to "+")

```
return element(by.css('.highcharts-tooltip-box+text>tspan')).getText();
```

P.S. Thank you for a github link, I created a pull request.